# Convert array in the list of values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array with such values:

```
 [{"meta_value":"Germany"},{"meta_value":"United States"}]
```

I need someway to convert it for list of values for autocomplete: **[Germany, United States].**

How to do it in the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var res = [{"meta_value":"Germany"},{"meta_value":"United States"}].map(function (el) {
   return el.meta_value;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.map()` to map one array to another array based on a mapping function:

```
var metaArr = [{"meta_value":"Germany"},{"meta_value":"United States"}];
var arrayOfStates = metaArr.map(function(item){return item.meta_value});
```

Simply use `arrayOfStates` as your source for the autocompletion.